# C вызов консольной команды и возвращение текстового значения

Tags: c, системное-программирование

Вопрос такой, гугл говорит, что выполнение консольных команд через system или exec возвращает только числовые значение (есть/нет ошибки). Собственно вопрос, допустим я хочу использовать ls ( к примеру ) и хочу вернуть текст, который эта команда возвращает при простом вызове консоли (список содержимого папки). Такой информации у великого гугла я не нашёл, может это игнор поисковых богов, но всё же... как это реализовать???

То есть я в коде делаю ls, а мне бы вернуло строку "файл1 папка1 ..."???

Comment: Смотрите в сторону каналов (pipe) и, особенно, функции `popen()`. Если нужно просто прочитать вывод команды, то `popen()` должно хватить.

Comment: Самое простое это вызвать команду через system или exec и перенаправить ее вывод в файл на диск. А потом парсить этот файл.

Comment: [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971647)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно что получилось для будущих поколений.

1. В консоль запрос на ввод
2. Вводим команду (пример `"ping google.com -c 4"`)
3. Получаем вывод в консоль пинга

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 128

int main(void) {
    char cmd[100];
    printf("Введите команду: ");
    fgets(cmd, 100, stdin);

    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE * fp;

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```