# Количество ФИЗИЧЕСКИХ процессоров на Linux c/c++

Tags: c++, linux, c

Не понимаю , как написать код на c/c++ для определения количества ФИЗИЧЕСКИХ процессоров (не ядер) .
Может можно как-то интерпретировать команды терминала на c/c++.

Еще интересно то ,что при
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | sort | uniq | wc -l
выдает 0 ,почему-то

А при
ls /sys/devices/system/node|grep node|wc -l
выдает 4,что верно

Comment: Смотри в исходники утилиты *turbostat* — там самая точная информация.

Comment: Ещё можешь поиграть с *lscpu*.

Answer (score 2):

В статье [Understanding Linux /proc/cpuinfo](http://doc.callmematthi.eu/static/webArticles/Understanding%20Linux%20_proc_cpuinfo.pdf)
есть достаточно понятное описание

> The kernel data Linux exposes in /proc/cpuinfowill show each logical
>   CPUwith a unique processor number. A logical CPUcan be a
>   hyperthreadingsibling,a shared core in a dual or quad core, or a
>   separate physical CPU. We must look at the siblings, CPUcores and core
>   id to tell the difference

и далее примеры, как определить сколько каких процессоров в вашей системе.

P.S.
если никто еще не напишет, то завтра попробую написать поподробней на русском...

Comment: Спасибо ,буду ждать ,хотя и сам еще попробую разобраться=)

Comment: Эта команда не работает в моем случае из-за того ,что в cpu нет записи "physical id " =(

Comment: @ilyasomov, странно, у вас какой Linux?. Вы внимательно смотрели глазами вывод `cat /proc/cpuinfo`? У меня (`cat /etc/issue\n
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`)  `physical  id` есть. Завтра гляну на работе на разных компах.

Comment: кстати AFAIK `physical id` есть только на x86/amd64; на других платформах содержимое cpuinfo может разительно отличаться и они могут просто не предоставлять информацию о физическом расположении ядер процессора... к чему это я... @ilyasomov, что за железо? и что в `/proc/cpuinfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Тут как вызвать из С консольную команду

[C вызов консольной команды и возвращение текстового значения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873367/c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/873709#873709)

и попробуйте

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: Этот греп на моём ноутбуке выдаёт 4, что неверно, так как в нём всего 1 процессор